# Unable to set ImageView within GridView to Bitmap converted from Drawable

Tags: java, android, gridview, bitmap, imageview

I have a **GridView** of **ImageView**s, and while I am building the GUI I currently want to convert some stock drawables into bitmaps, and set the ImageViews to these. They currently just come out as blanks, but as far as I can tell the code is along the correct lines.

The GridView XML: (it expands as more elements are added)

```
        <com.example.tristan.studentshare.ExpandingGridView
            android:id="@+id/achievement_grid"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
        </com.example.tristan.studentshare.ExpandingGridView>
```

The row_grid_achievements XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/achievement_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/achievement_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `Achievement` being displayed in the `GridView`:

```
public class Achievement {

private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private Integer progress;
private Bitmap icon;

public Achievement(String id, String name, String description, Integer progress, Bitmap icon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.progress = progress;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public Integer getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public Bitmap getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
```

}

The `GridView` adapter override:

```
static class RecordHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageItem;

    public RecordHolder(TextView txtTitle, ImageView imageItem) {
        this.txtTitle = txtTitle;
        this.imageItem = imageItem;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder(
                (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.achievement_text),
                (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.achievement_image));

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else holder = (RecordHolder)row.getTag();

    Achievement achievement = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(achievement.getName());
    holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(achievement.getIcon());
    return row;
}
```

The implementation in the `Activity`:

```
ExpandingGridView gridView;
ArrayList<Achievement> gridArray = new ArrayList<Achievement>();
AchievementGridViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    //TODO:Actual Achievement details from server
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        gridArray.add(new Achievement("0", "Achv" + i, "test", 50, icon));
    }

    gridView = (ExpandingGridView) findViewById(R.id.achievement_grid);
    adapter = new AchievementGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid_achievements, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The visual result:
The grid items should have an icon above them similar to the "profile picture"
[image: Damn.]

Comment: What does your row_grid_achievements layout file look like.

Comment: Also if your images are already drawables there is no reason to convert them to bitmap, just use setDrawable on the ImageView directly.

Comment: I shall edit the post to include row_grid_achievements, and try that.
I'm deciding to opt for Bitmaps, since the actual images will later likely be Bitmaps (user profile photos from their gallery, etc)

Comment: @Ben I used setImageDrawable in the adapter class getView function, after changing Achievement's icon field to a Drawable type, and this worked.
My question still stands however - why didn't it work for a Bitmap? Or did I incorrectly convert the Drawable into a null Bitmap?

Comment: Most likely something was wrong with the conversion to a bitmap. I find typically it's better to just go with drawables where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, instead of using GridView, I used RecyclerView, with a GridLayoutManager (http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

To have the elements I wanted displayed in the grid, the RecyclerView uses an Adapter and inflates each grid element with a custom layout, in the following link they use a CardView as the layout root (http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)

To get a Drawable instance from Resources, I use the following code:

```
    Drawable d1 = ResourceCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.picture, null);
    //or , depending on where your Drawable is,
    Drawable d2 = ResourceCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.mipmap.picture, null);
```

In the code where it actually comes to setting the ImageView to a particular Drawable, I used the code:

```
    //Using the Resource ID
    myImageView.setImageResource(myResourceID);
    //Using a Drawable instance
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Note that in the AndroidHive link above, whichever of the the above two lines of code would be used in the adapter class, in the Overrided method '**onBindViewHolder**'

Answer (score 0):

In the getView() method of your adapter change the below line

```
holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(achievement.getIcon());
```

according to below

```
holder.imageItem.setBackgroundDrawable(achievement.getIcon());
```

I hope it works

Comment: That is a deprecated function and requires a Drawable, I'm opting for Bitmaps as the images I'll be using will probably be Bitmaps.

Comment: This isn't correct you should only change the background if you intend to set the background. This can lead to unintended consequences and can increase overdraw.